# Intended way to push default data to CouchDB with node.couchapp.js

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I have a couchapp that I'm writing, and am using node.couchapp.js ( https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js ) to push files (attachments, views, etc.) from the filesystem to CouchDB.  I would like to also push non-design documents; what is the intended way of doing so?

EDIT:

This is roughly what I have for an app.js ATM:

```
ddoc = { _id:'_design/app' };

couchapp.loadAttachments(ddoc, path.join(__dirname, 'attachments'));

module.exports = ddoc;
```

And this is my data.json:

```
[
    { "_id": "doc1" },
    { "_id": "doc2" },
    { "_id": "doc3" },
    ...
    { "_id": "docN" },
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just specify document id without `_design/` prefix and it will be counted as regular document.

Comment: I've updated my quesiton; can you please give more detail?  I have a large number of documents I'd like to push, but it's not clear to me how to say "also load all of the contents of data.json".